# Merging dokku's version-controlled directories with docker's volumes

Tags: docker, dokku

Is it possible, within a push to [Dokku](http://dokku.viewdocs.io/dokku/), to copy files (overwriting if duplicate) from what is pushed into a volume?

Currently I have a Dokku app set up where directory `/a` has certain files in it that are version controlled, but I also have a volume mounted on `/a` so I can upload files to it from a web interface.

The problem I'm facing is that when I push to the Dokku machine, the volume is mounted over the directory `/a`, so any files that are pushed up vanish.

I'd like to preserve the pushed files while retaining the persistence of a volume over this directory.

What I am trying to do—though open to other suggestions—is copy the files from the pushed data directly to the volume on the server, so when it is mounted the pushed files are still there.

Is the best way to do this through a plugin? If so, are there existing plugins to solve this issue? I was going to try and do it through the built-in [docker](https://www.docker.com/) options plugin, but it looks like it's only passing things to `docker run`, which means I can't run `docker cp` within it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so, as that isn't how docker volumes work. I would suggest uploading to a subfolder of `/a` if that is possible.